# Why do so many "photorealistic" shots dont look real?

Tags: rendering, photorealism

I see many photorealistic shots but some of them are looking real but you feel that something is off but i don't can figure out what it is
example:[image: example]

Comment: What jumps out to me is that the wall texture is a little too much, and the frame around the door is strange in a couple of ways.

Comment: One of the biggest challenges in photorealism is that things often look "too perfect" - imperfections are the key  - things that often get overlooked are things like dust in the air and or/on the tops of surfaces and deformations in things like a floor with a "soft spot", or a desk that isn't quite flush against a wall. Even _textured lighting_ makes a huge difference (example here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJ56n1CzRbI). Lastly, use some kind of depth of field - eyes and even cameras will start to blur things around the edges of the image -use sparingly, but have some there.